# Can we use form with Stateless widget in flutter or it's a bad way to do that?

Tags: flutter

I'm using Stateless Widget that doesn't need anything to be change in that class while running but i'm using a formkey in this class so is it necessary to convert this class to stateful widget or it is ok to leave it with Stateless Widget.
Note: I'm not using TextEditing controllers in this Widget while i'm using the onSaved method.